# Line integral under closed sign

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, line-integrals, greens-theorem

Compute
$$
\oint_{C}\left[\left(2x - y^{3}\right)\mathrm{d}x - xy\,\mathrm{d}y\right],
$$
where $C$ is the boundary of region enclosed by $x^{2} + y^{2} = 1$ and $x^{2} + y^{2} = 9$.

I am confused because it's integration is under closed sign but both the curves are different which don't intersect then what should by my limit ?.

Comment: You have here the annulus between the first circle and the second one. Polar ccordinates could be handy here...

Comment: Hint: The Extended Green's Theorem. See: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02-multivariable-calculus-fall-2007/readings/simpl_conctd_reg.pdf

Comment: Do you have the answer? Can you try with the given hints?

Comment: Answer is 60pie

Comment: I can simply do it with green's theorem but in question i have to do it with principle method also

Comment: I don{t know what is [principal method[, but if you mean with parametrization and etc. then it is going to be a rahter lengthy solution...but not impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\oint_C (2x-y^3)dx-(xy)dy=\iint_R\left(\frac{\partial(-xy)}{\partial x}-\left(\frac{\partial(2x-y^3)}{\partial y}\right)\right)\,dA=$$

$$=\iint_R\left(-y-3y^2\right)\,dx\,dy=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^3 r(-r\sin\theta-3r^2\sin^2\theta)\,dr\,d\theta=$$

$$=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^3-\left(r^2\sin\theta+3r^3\sin^2\theta\right)=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(-\frac{26}3\sin\theta-60\sin^2\theta\right)\,d\theta=$$

$$=0-\left.30(\theta-\sin\theta\cos\theta)\right|_0^{2\pi}=-60\pi$$

$$=$$